# Logstash - convert JSON to readable format - during logging to a file

Tags: json, logging, logstash, human-readable

I have a Logstash configuration as given below:

```
 input {
  udp {
  port => 5043
  codec => json
  }
 }

 output {
  file {
  path => "/logfile.log"
  }
 }
```

I am trying to log messages in the "logfile.log" which are more readable.

So if my input data is like {"attr1":"val1","attr2":"val2"}

I want to write it in the log as:

attr1_val1 | attr2_val2

Basically converting data from JSON to a readable format.

What should I be modifying in my Logstash configuration to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message_format option of the [file](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/file) output allows you to specify how each message should be formatted. If the keys of your messages are fixed and known you can simply do this:

```
output {
  file {
    message_format => "attr1_%{attr1} | attr2_%{attr2}"
    ...
  }
}
```

To handle arbitrary fields you'll probably have to write some custom Ruby code using the [ruby filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/ruby). The following filter, for example, produces the same results as above but doesn't require you to hardcode the names of the fields:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => '
      values = []
      event.to_hash.each { |k, v|
        next if k.start_with? "@"
        values << "#{k}_#{v.to_s}"
      }
      event["myfield"] = values.join(" | ")
    '
  }
}

output {
  file {
    message_format => "%{myfield}"
    ...
  }
}
```